# How to get passing parameter count in a function NUNIT mocking assertion?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

How to get the parameters count which is passing to the function using Nunit mocking for assertion and that function called inside another function.

For e.g:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public void ProcessData(IEnumerable<EventData> events)
{
    List<TestClass> testClasses = new();

    events.ForEach(msg => {
       var testClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(msg.EventBody.ToString());

       if(testClass != null)
       {
          testClasses.Add(testClass);
       }
   });

   if(testClasses.Count > 0)
   {
       BulkUpdateData(testClasses);
   }
}

public void BulkUpdateData(List<TestClass> testClasses)
{ ... }
```

Now, I need to do unit testing this "ProcessData" method.
For this using NUnit framework in .Net 6.0.

I can pass test data to "ProcessData" method by mocking while writing unit test cases.
But here my case is,

**Consider now I'm passing 10 values in a list to "ProcessData". In that only 8 got passed to "BulkUpdateData" method since 2 values are not got deserialized due to invalid data.
Here how to get this BulkUpdateData got 8 values inside the "ProcessData" method.**

I need to get this count value for assertion.

Kindly suggest on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your ProcessData() method needs to return something. Either an `int` representing the count of processed testclasses, or `List<TestClass>`.
With your ProcessData() method now returning something, you can then go ahead and write your asserts, knowing exactly how many testclasses were passed to BulkUpdateData() method.

```
 public IEnumerable<TestClass> ProcessData(IEnumerable<EventData> events)
    {
        List<TestClass> testClasses = new();

        events.ForEach(msg => {
            var testClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(msg.EventBody.ToString());

            if (testClass != null)
            {
                testClasses.Add(testClass);
            }
            
        });
        if (testClasses.Count > 0)
        {
            BulkUpdateData(resultOfProcessData);
        }
        return testClasses;
    }
```

If I misunderstood your question and actually, you want to unit test BulkUpdateData() method, in your `[TestFixture]` you could add an instance variable to hold either the count or the list of TestClass objects. And you could take advantage of the [[OrderAttribute]](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/order.html) and organize your tests like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTests
{

    List<TestClass> resultOfProcessData = new();


    [Test]
    [Order(1)]
    public void ProcessDataUnitTest()
    {
        resultOfProcessData = ProcessData(events);
    }


    [Test]
    [Order(2)]
    public void BulkUpdateDataUnitTest()
    {
        if (resultOfProcessData.Count > 0)
        {
            BulkUpdateData(resultOfProcessData);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TestClass> ProcessData(IEnumerable<EventData> events)
    {
        List<TestClass> testClasses = new();

        events.ForEach(msg => {
            var testClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(msg.EventBody.ToString());

            if (testClass != null)
            {
                testClasses.Add(testClass);
            }
            
        });
        
        return testClasses;
    }

    public void BulkUpdateData(List<TestClass> testClasses)
    { ... }
}
```

Hope this helps.